# How to annotate a query with column from a relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I have two models, `Owner` and `Dog`. Dogs belong to Owners and Owners have many Dogs.

Can I query for Owners and annotate them with `most_food_needed_for_pet`, which is the `food_needed` column of the `Dog` with the max `lifespan`? I know I can accomplish this with multiple queries but I this should be possible with only one query using `Arel`.

My initial attempt was

```
Owner.
  joins(:dogs).
  select(Dog.arel_table[:food_needed].as('most_food_needed_for_pet')).
  select(Dog.arel_table[:lifespan].maximum).
  group('dogs.owner_id')
```

But that incorrectly annotates each owner with the max `lifespan`, and the `food_needed` of the first `Dog` in the database instead of the longest living `Dog`.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = Dog.arel_table
o = Owner.arel_table
Owner.
  select( o[Arel.star], d[:lifespan], d[:food_needed].as('most_food_needed_for_pet')).
  joins(:dogs).
  group(:owner_id).
  having( dogs: { lifespan: d[:lifespan].maximum } )
```

[edited to remove bare `*` in case of field overlap]

Comment: I ran that and I get a Mysql2:error, check your syntax around `AS max_id`.

Comment: What's the SQL that it's generating?